# strange behaviour while pressing enter when recieving input with conditions with cin

Tags: c++, cin

I have this code that checks if index is an integer between 1 and the size of a vector member called options_ (menu implementation):

```
int ConsoleMenu::GetSelection() {
int index;
std::cout << "Please enter your selection index. " << std::endl;
while (!(std::cin >> index) || std::cin.get() != '\n' || index < 1 ||    index > options_.size()) {
  std::cout << "Error. index must be a valid integer. Try again: " <<   std::endl;
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
  }
}
```

but sometimes when I input a number and press enter it seems as if the program does not recognize I pressed enter. Can someone please help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems like a very confusing way to do it. Call `getline()`, then parse the string it returns to see if it's a number in the desired range.

Comment: but I want it to be an integer in a certain range, not other type...

Comment: You have two input operations, so the program will wait for the user to input two lines.  Barmar is suggesting you do just one input operation, and then try interpreting that single input two different ways.

Comment: Can someone please translate it to code, Because I don't understand what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

Read a line with `getline()`, parse it using a `std::stringstream`, and test if it meets your criteria:

```
int ConsoleMenu::GetSelection() {
    std::cout << "Please enter your selection index. " << std::endl;
    while (true) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::stringstream linest(line);
        int index;
        if ((linest >> index) && index >= 1 && index < options_.size()) {
            return index;
        }
        std::cout << "Error. index must be a valid integer. Try again: " <<   std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: is getline() a cpp 98 cin function?
Because its not being recognized.

Comment: I changed to `std::getline()`, I think that's the C++98 function.

Comment: Still it says "no matching function".

Comment: Sorry, was calling it wrong. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/